# powershell unable to index into an object of type microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I know there are some other posts with almost the same title, but i couldn't find what i was looking for ...
First let me explain you what i am trying to do: 
I need to upload a few hundred documents to sharepoint 2010 document library using a powershell script that is collecting data from an excel worksheet. Each document has many properties and 80% of them will be completed at the import time. The upload is working fine, but when i am trying to update each document properties, ... well, there are where the problems appeared.

The problem is that there are several lookup columns that i want to update, but some of them are not working ... I mean there are 3 lookup columns (single value) that are updating and 2 columns that are not updating. I am using internal name of the field for all of them and all lookup columns are indexed columns (because i am using the restricted delete behaviour).
I tried to delete the index of the column that is not updating, but this did not worked.
I tried to delete and recreate the column, but still not working.
I tried to use the id of the field or the display name, but still not working.

```
$Spfield=$Spfile.Item.Fields["MyLookupField"]
$Spfile.Item[$Spfield.ID]=($spweb.Lists["AnotherList"]).GetItemById($LookupIdValue)
$Spfile.item.Update()
```

It throws this exception:

```
Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
```

The same exception for this: **$Splistitem[$Spfield.ID]=$LookupIdValue.ToString()+";#"+$LookupValue**

If I write this  **$Spfile.Item["Internal_x0020_Name"]=$lookupRegion**  I am receiving the following error message:

```
Unable to index into an object of type microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem
```

For this **$Splistitem.Item("MyColumn")=$lookupRegion** I was receiving this exception

```
Exception calling "set_item" with "2" arguments. The column 'MyColumn' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.
```

Any help would be gladly appreciated. Thank you in advance !

Comment: I want to mention that the columns of this document library were created in 2 steps: the lookup columns created in first step are working fine. The lookup columns created in second step are not working, not even one. It seems to be important, but I cannot figure out WHY.